# Accessing Pandora playback data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pandora

I know that there is no official Pandora API for iPhone devs, but I'm wondering if anyone has figured out a way to access user's playback data in objective-c. Things like songs, artists, stations, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to accessing the data directly: nope. You might be able to get to some of it on a jailbroken device, if the Pandora app stores things like that, but otherwise you’re out of luck; apps are sandboxed and can’t get at each others’ data.

You might, though, try scraping information from users’ profile pages—if they’re willing to give you the URL to that (in the format `pandora.com/people/[whoever]`), there’s probably a fair bit of data you can glean there.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Would there be a way, if my app were running in the background, to grab the information about songs as they are played on the Pandora app?

Comment: Definitely not. Neither the multitasking APIs nor the aforementioned sandboxing would allow it. Sorry.